# Github Pull Request Builder with Jenkins not triggering

Tags: github, jenkins, pull-request

We follow a github flow.

Developers push their code to their forks and do pull requests in original repository.

What I wanted to do is trigger build with Pull Requests not merge or anything. After the build It should comment in the PR that build successful or not.

I was following instructions from: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+pull+request+builder+plugin

Problem is I see logs as:

> Jun 12, 2017 3:11:58 PM INFO
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.PullRequestGHEventSubscriber
>   onEvent Received PULL_REQUEST for https://github.com/organization/repo
>   from 192.30.252.42 ⇒ http://our-jenkins-server.com/github-webhook/ Jun
>   12, 2017 3:11:58 PM INFO org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbRootAction
>   handleAction Checking PR #59 for organization/repo

But not any trigger. Should it work like this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, then realized I needed to add this option in the job:

```
GitHub project
    Project url
```

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: I have similar problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58958189/ghprb-plugin-in-jenkins-unable-to-trigger-build . Do you have any idea on how to fix this?